# eth not defined error in react

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether, etherscan

Encountering the eth not defined error in react app, can someone help me with this? This app is with regards the DApp in solidity.

[image: eth not defined error]

Comment: Please share the code so that we can help. It could be a missing dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React if you are using Functional components I would suggest using the web3 Library IN your component add a variable:

```
const ethRef = useRef<Web3>(null);
```

In a useEffect which runs only when the component is mounted updated the ethRef reference with something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
if (!window.ethereum) {
  return;
}
ethRef.current = new Web3(window.ethereum);}, []);
```

From there any where in your component you can use the web3 provider and its helper function and classes like this:

```
const contractInstance = new ethRef.current.eth.Contract(contractABI,contractAddress);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t seem to be importing web3 at the top of the file...

See this [Stackexchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/43498/how-to-import-web3-into-a-react-project) answer for how to add web3.